# Laravel - How to use isDirty()

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to use Laravel `isDirty()` which helps me to get only modified values,

But there is a problem when I'm trying to use, it always `return false`

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {

        $client = Client::find($id);

        dd($client->isDirty('name'));

}
```

It always `return false`.

Answer (score 4):

It returns `false` because you haven't *done* anything to `$client`.

Thus, it is not "dirty" - it is "clean".

If you do something like `$client->name = str_random(40);` it'll become dirty.

Comment: I have modified client fields.

Comment: @MuhammadJavedBaloch when you do `$client = Client::find($id);` it means it's clean. You didn't modified it yet.

Comment: @MuhammadJavedBaloch Not in the code you've shown you haven't.

Answer (score 1):

To get only modified attributes, you need to use the `getDirty()` method. `isDirty()` only shows if there are any modified attributes:

```
$client = Client::find($id);
$client->name = 'Some New Name';
$modifiedAttributes = $client->getDirty();
```

If you want to check if any of properties were modified in the submitted form or not, you can do it like this:

```
if ($client->name === $request->name)
```

Comment: Re: the second bit, note that accessors/mutators may break this, as will the `===` for integer-casted values (which will be strings in the request, but integers in the model).